# grep/search for multiple lines in a file

Tags: grep, full-text-search

Let's say I have a file with a long nested array, that's formatted like this:

```
array(
   'key1' => array(
       'val1' => 'val',
       'val2' => 'val',
       'val3' => 'val',
   ),
   'key2' => array(
       'val1' => 'val',
       'val2' => 'val',
       'val3' => 'val',
   ),
   //etc...
);
```

what I would like to do is have a way to grep/search a file, and by knowing key 1, get all the lines (the sub-array) it contains. is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with `grep` but you should be able to do it with `awk` or `sed`:

```
sed -n '/key1/,/)/p' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are no more levels of nested arrays, then this should work:

```
awk '/key1/,/\)/' my_input_file
```

Basically, it prints from ***key1*** to next closing bracket ***)***.

Comment: Right answer, but useless use of `cat`

Comment: Ah, indeed. I will fix this right away.

Comment: I tried what you said, awk throws a 'backslash not last character on line' error

Comment: I'm not sure. My knowledge of sed/awk is rudimentary. It works on mawk though - I tested. Maybe there's some difference in how it's handled.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a fixed number of items in the array, you can use the `-A` (lines after switch) with grep:

```
grep -A4 'key1' myfile 

   -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
          Print NUM  lines  of  trailing  context  after  matching  lines.
          Places   a  line  containing  a  group  separator  (--)  between
          contiguous groups of matches.  With the  -o  or  --only-matching
          option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
```

There is also `-B` for before lines as well.

Comment: Nice, I did not know about this one.